# PrimeNG DataTable Editor shows wrong value

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng, primeng-datatable, two-way-binding

I face an issue about Datatable Editor

My table is datatable of PrimeNG, this table can edit any cell of row and all cell is required:

here is the requiment of Datatable:

- can edit any cell
- validate any cell (required)

when I finished 2 requirements, the datatable raise up an issue, and this issue is in the image below
[image]

please help me out of this issue

and here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cGDzMQNu7obbz9YXWyHY?p=preview)

Here is the importance of Code:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data[col.field]" pInputText required="true" [name]="col.field" />
```

if I add attribute `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` the issue will be resolved but the validation will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made a mistake in the `name` attribute. Replace

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data[col.field]" pInputText required="true" [name]="col.field" />
```

with

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data[col.field]" pInputText required="true" [name]="data[col.field]" />
```

In your case, `col.field` equals *name* so for the whole first column, all your inputs have the same name hence the problem.

Comment: Could you also help this bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414409/datatable-edit-can-not-validate-with-two-dimensional